# access array elements in java outside the loop

Tags: java, arrays

I am developing a simple program to print seat numbers, where the row are numbered from 1-5 and columns from a-e. the code i am using is as follows

```
public class JavaApplication5 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int j =1,k;
        int i;
        char c;
        String[] arr = new String[25];
        for( i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
        {
            while(j <= 5)
            {
                for(k = 97;k < 102; k++)
                {
                    c = ((char)k);
                    arr[i] = j + "" + c;
                    System.out.println(arr[i]);
                }
                j++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this displays desired result. but when I print an element outside the for loop I get the result as null like below

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j =1,k;
    int i;
    char c;
    String[] arr = new String[25];
    for( i = 0;i < arr.length;i++)
    {
        while(j <= 5)
        {
            for(k = 97;k < 102; k++)
            {
                c = ((char)k);
                arr[i] = j + "" + c;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arr[6]);
}
```

how to solve this?

Comment: If you have a solution which displays the desired result what is your question?

Answer (score 1):

this will leave all elements as null

`String[] arr = new String[25];`

this will iterate until `j == 5` so only until `arr[5]`

```
while(j <= 5) {
   j++;
}
```

Therefore `arr[6]` is still null

Answer (score 1):

Change

> arr[j] = j + "" + c;

instead of

> arr[i] = j + "" + c;

Now it works.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int j = 1, k;
    int i;
    char c;
    String[] arr = new String[25];
    for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        while (j <= 5) {
            for (k = 97; k < 102; k++) {
                c = ((char) k);
                arr[j] = j + "" + c;
            }
            j++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(arr[1]);
    System.out.println(arr[2]);
    System.out.println(arr[3]);
    System.out.println(arr[4]);
    System.out.println(arr[5]);
    System.out.println(arr[6]); // null because your check j <= 5 in while loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the array elements normally outside of the loop. In your example, arr[6] is just null. The fault is not in the way you access it. (Although i cant see the bug yet ;))

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code is that you simply write 5 time on index 1, then 5 time on index 2 and so on.
So you never wrote on index 6.
Your code should be changed to code below:

```
String[] arr = new String[25];
int i = 0;
int j = 1;
while (j <= 5) {
    for (k = 97; k < 102; k++) {
        c = ((char) k);
        arr[i++] = j + "" + c;
    }
    j++;
}
System.out.println(arr[6]);
```

Because your loops  run 5*5 times, then your `i` index will never pass `arr` array length.
But you better control it like this to prevent your code from being error prone:

```
if(i < arr.length) {
    arr[i++] = j + "" + c;
} else {
    break;
}
```